# Android multiple screen size and avoid duplicating images

Tags: android, resources, screen, resolution

I have an app that displays a bitmap in a TextView as a "drawableTop":

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/bitmap"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text" />
```

The bitmap comes from a PNG file in the res/drawable folder, let's call it bitmap.png.

I need to support multiple screen sizes and densities, and want to find the cheapest way (in term of how many PNG files I need to have in res/* folders) to do it.

**Various densities: Phones only**

I've come to the conclusion that it's enough to have the bitmap.png in res/drawable-xhdpi folder. When being displayed on phones with high density, it will be displayed as is, while on phones will lower density, it will be scaled down automatically.
In other words, no need for having lower resolution versions of the bitmap.png in res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-mdpi etc.
Basically **only one version** of the PNG file is enough for all phones.

**Various densities: Tablets as well**

Now, the problem arises if I want to support as well tablets: large and xlarge screens.
On tablets, I want the aspect ratio of the icon to be the same as it was on phones: If the bitmap took 1/4 of the screen on phones, I want it to take 1/4 of the screen on tablets. I cannot reuse the same PNG file as before or it would look too small since the tablet just has more pixels... So for tablets I need a higher res PNG. And this applies both to large screen and xlarge screens.

Which results in the need for 3 folders, and 3 versions of the PNG:

1: res/drawable-xhdpi/bitmap.png
2: res/drawable-large-xhdpi/bitmap.png
3: res/drawable-xlarge-xhdpi/bitmap.png

But 1 and 2 are basically lower res versions of 3.

So is there an easy way to have a single folder not 3?

Comment: Have you thought of using Vectors instead of raster based images.  If you want consistent scaling at any resolution,  a vector based solution is always going to provide better results than rasters,  take a look at https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only one image for all resolutions, why not keep in res/drawable and res/drawable-land folders?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about cheapest way to do this (not adding more than one image in drawables), then use **9-Patch Images**. If you dont know about it, then have a look n learn usage here:

http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html

http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/creating-custom-drawn-button.html

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, you don't need different orientated images for tablet or phone.
If you want the image to take 1/4 size on both devices, then define your image in your xml as using d(i)p. This will scale the image to the same size on all devices.

d(i)p is scaled relative to 640x480 (or 480x640 resolution for portrait orientation).
So you can calculate different combinations of resolutions to cover 1/4 screen space, such as 320x240 or 240x320

If you want control over the scaling of your image, I would suggest putting the image in an ImageView. This will allow you to use the **android:scaleType** property to scale your image how you wish.

You can set the background of your TextView to be transparent, and have the ImageView below it contained within a relativeLayout of your desired size to achieve the same effect as you current have, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp" 
    >

    <!-- Images at the top of the xml are drawn on the bottom! -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bitmap" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Also consider using [alias resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources).

This will allow you to define an xml file which will act as if it's the real PNG image (and is referenced as such in R.drawable. , but is actually a reference to another image.

From the linked Google documentation:

> To create an alias to an existing drawable, use the  element.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:src="@drawable/icon_ca" />
> ```
>
> If you save this file as icon.xml (in an alternative resource
>   directory, such as res/drawable-en-rCA/), it is compiled into a
>   resource that you can reference as R.drawable.icon, but is actually an
>   alias for the R.drawable.icon_ca resource (which is saved in
>   res/drawable/).